# locationManager:didEnterRegion not called when entered in provided region

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-location, geofencing

I am trying to implement geo-fencing using GoogleMaps in iOS. I've initialised CLLocationManager object with required properties also provided region to start monitoring, using following code.

```
    private func setupGoogleMapServicecs() {
       let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: CLLocationDegrees(latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(longitude), zoom: 6.0)
       let mapRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
       mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: mapRect, camera: camera)
       mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
       mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
       mapView.delegate = self
       self.view.addSubview(mapView)

       let circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(longitude))
       //-33.86 & 151.20
      // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
       let marker = GMSMarker()
       marker.position = circleCenter
       marker.title = "Title"
       marker.snippet = "Snippet"
       marker.icon = UIImage(named: "ico-pin-map")
       marker.map = mapView

      let circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: CLLocationDistance(circularRadius))
      circ.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.35, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05)
      circ.strokeColor = .red
      circ.strokeWidth = 5
      circ.map = mapView

      self.registerLocationManager()
   }



private func registerLocationManager() {
      self.locationManager.delegate = self
      self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
      self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() 

      let centrePosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(longitude))
      region = CLCircularRegion(center: centrePosition, radius: CLLocationDistance(circularRadius), identifier: "test")
      region.notifyOnEntry = true
      region.notifyOnExit = true
      self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
  }
```

Moreover, i've configured keys in info.plist like this
[image]

Furthermore, I've implemented following delegate methods to test which one may be triggered when entered/exit from provided region.

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("test")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

        //Testing Code
        let alert = iAlert()
        alert.showSingleOptionOkAlertWith(Title: "Geofencing", message: "didRangeBeacons", presenter: self)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
        print("The monitored regions are: \(manager.monitoredRegions)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {

        //Testing Code
        let alert = iAlert()
        alert.showSingleOptionOkAlertWith(Title: "Geofencing", message: "didExitRegion", presenter: self)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {

        //Testing Code
        let alert = iAlert()
        alert.showSingleOptionOkAlertWith(Title: "Geofencing", message: "didEnterRegion", presenter: self)
    }
```

Only for once this method called "didEnterRegion" when i stood for the 5 mins in the specified region, but after that it is not called again. 
Please suggest if i've missed any step or anything else i can try?
I want to integrate it on **GoogleMap**, i did tried on **MKMapKit** and it's working.

Comment: The delegate is called when you "enter" the region, so if you stay in, you will not have additional callbacks

Comment: Yes the delegate is called, but with a delay of 5-7 mins or even more. Isn't it possible that method should be called immediately after entering the region?

Comment: Are you registering while outside the region ?

Comment: If you want to monitor regions you should request "always" permission, not "when in use".  You should call `requestState(for: CLRegion)` when you start monitoring the region to determine whether you are already inside or outside. You can expect a delay before getting a region entry/exit notification

Comment: What is the value of `circularRadius`?

Comment: @Paulw11 circularRadius value is 20. Also i've tried using "always" permission, Native alert for confirmation doesn't show. it is shown only when i use "request when in use app".

Comment: The alert is only shown the first time you request permissions. You need always permission if you want region notification to work in the background. 20m is very small. A region size of 100-200m will probably give faster response.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am going out to test for `requestState(for: CLRegion)` and implemented the delegate `locationManager: didDetermineState`. Hope it may help, if it doesn't then afterwards i'll test with `circularRadius = 100-200`

Comment: @Paulw11 `locationManager: didDetermineState` is always giving a state `.inside`. Even if i enter the region or start the app, this code gives me `.inside` everytime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184471/discussion-between-paulw11-and-shahriyar-ahmed).